# Relacionamento no Model com Nome de Coluna Alias

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou fazendo uma consulta com `union` no Laravel.

```
$first      = Friendship::selectRaw('id, userid, friendid, friendid as friend')
->where('userid', '=', $idUser)
->where('confirmed_friendship', '=', 1)
->whereHas('user_friends', function($where){
    $where->where('suspended', '=', 0)->where('deleted', '=', 0);
});

$content    = Friendship::selectRaw('id, userid, friendid, userid as friend')
->where('friendid', '=', $idUser)
->where('confirmed_friendship', '=', 1)
->whereHas('friends', function($where){
    $where->where('suspended', '=', 0)->where('deleted', '=', 0);
})
->union($first);

$content    = $content->get();
```

E gostaria de fazer um relacionamento com outro tabela **usando o alias que eu coloquei no** `SELECT`.

```
public function user_friends(){
    // Gostaria de indicar aqui a coluna que eu renomeei para `friend`

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'friendid');
}
```

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: **Eu gostaria de fazer um relacionamento com outro tabela é isso é possivel?** Sim é possivel, mas, poderia também disponibilizar o `model` e qual campos relaciona!

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta para que você e outros usuários possam entender melhor o que eu quero.